# How can I run my Thin server as a different user on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, thin

I run an Ubuntu 10.04 VPS which hosts 2 Thin processes running Ruby On Rails behind Nginx. I control the Thin processes via a /etc/init.d startup script as a regular user. In my Thin config file I specify:

```
user: www-data
group: www-data
```

And in my Thin logs, when I start the server, I see

```
>> Changing process privilege to www-data:www-data
```

Good sign. Problem is when I run `ps -ef` my Thin processes are running as the user I login as -- the user I run `/etc/init.d/thin start` as.

How can I get the Thin processes started as www-data:www-data when I run `/etc/init.d/thin start` as the user I log into the server as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sudo to run a command as any user:group with these options:

```
sudo -u www-data -g www-data /etc/init.d/thin start
```

-u sets the www-data user and -g sets the www-data group

Comment: This does seem to be the proper way to do it on Ubuntu Linux. It works for other daemons, but not the daemon that I originally posted about (thin). That's due to my RVM environment though..

Comment: Ah, then you will want to use rvmsudo. If you are using rvm, NEVER use sudo. Just replace sudo with rvmsudo like so :

`rvmsudo -u www-data -g www-data /etc/init.d/thin start`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make an :

```
sudo -c www-data /etc/init.d/thin start
```

But if your Thin server is listening the port 80, you will need the root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you're an ordinary user, you will not be able to switch the process ownership to some other user.  You will need to run the /etc/init.d/thin script as root to do this.

So, you can do something like `sudo /etc/init.d/thin start`.